# How do I filter issues that block issues in a specific sprint in another project?

Tags: jira, jql

I have two projects A and B and want to filter for all issues in B that block issues in a specific sprint in A. Is there a way to do that in JQL?

Comment: How do you track if a issue in project b blocks your issue in project a? With issuelinks?

Comment: @Runningriot: If that's the answer, can you illustrate the JQL expression for it: "all issues in project B that block issues in project A". It's not clear to me how your comment addresses that.

Answer (score -1):

You may refer to [this](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/Filter-Query-for-related-projects-in-JIRA/qaq-p/454363) Atlassian question where this is answered. For more options on the same category, you can check [this](https://www.j-tricks.com/jqlt-links-functions.html) site as well.

You could try to use the `linkedIssuesInProject()` function as like the below to fetch the results that you intend to:

```
issue in linkedIssuesInProject("TST","is blocked by")
```

**EDIT-1:**

You need to add the JQL Tricks plugin. Please refer to the following links for the required details:

1. [JQL Tricks plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/31399/jql-tricks-plugin?hosting=server&tab=overview)
2. [Issues post JQL Tricks plugin installation](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Marketplace-Apps-questions/JQL-Tricks-Plugin-issue/qaq-p/69828)

Hope this helps!

Kindly let me know if this helps you solve your requirement!

Comment: Looking for "filter for all issues in B that block issues in a specific sprint in A" in JQL. This doesn't even parse.

Comment: @orome, Kindly check my updated answer! A downvote was unnecessary though! :(

Comment: @orome, did you get a chance to check my updated answer? Did that help?